# Docker - executing mkdir, chown & chgrp after the container is up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a docker container, using docker-compose, which mounts a volume on the local filesystem (for the container's /var/www/html) then adds a directory called maps and chowns and chmods is to www-data, so that the web server can write files into it.

I've tried a couple of approaches, using an entrypoint.sh script like this:

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
COPY apache-config.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers
RUN service apache2 restart
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 0755 /entrypoint.sh
```

docker-compose.yml (stuff in {} just comes from a .env file)

```
version: '2'

services:
  webserver:
    build: ./docker/webserver
    image: web
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./web:${APACHE_DOC_ROOT}
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      - HTTP_ROOT=http://${DOCKER_HOST_IP}:${DOCKER_HOST_PORT}/
      - PHP_TMP_DIR=${PHP_TMP_DIR}
      - APACHE_LOG_DIR=${APACHE_LOG_DIR}
      - APACHE_DOC_ROOT=${APACHE_DOC_ROOT}/
      - SERVER_ADMIN_EMAIL=${SERVER_ADMIN_EMAIL}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir /var/www/html/maps
chown www-data /var/www/html/maps
chgrp www-data /var/www/html/maps
exec "$@"
```

I've also tried without any of the entrypoint.sh stuff, just adding this into the composer.yml (after the environment key):

```
    command: bash -c "mkdir /var/www/html/maps && chown www-data /var/www/html/maps && chgrp www-data /var/www/html/maps"
```

But both these approaches seem to give no error in docker-compose logs other than

> webserver_1 exited with code 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Fortis and @whites11 pointed out I am overriding the existing CMD in the [original PHP 5.6 Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/ddc7084c8a78ea12f0cfdceff7d03c5a530b787e/5.6/apache/Dockerfile).  The various combinations of CMD and ENTRYPOINT are described in the [Dockerfile reference - Understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) - I believe I am in the bottom right of the matrix, combining the "CMD exec_cmd" from the original Dockerfile (in this case "CMD apache-foreground") with ENTRYPOINT [“exec_entry”, “p1_entry”].

So, in my Dockerfile I just need to run the apache-foreground script that was set-up in the original Dockerfile, like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh", "apache2-foreground"]
```

And leave the entrypoint.sh ending with:

```
exec "$@"
```

This allows me to do what I need to (create a mounted volume in my docker-compose.yml to the local filesystem, then use the entrypoint.sh to create and chown + chmod a directory inside that mount with a local user & group from inside the container) and then execute /apache2-foreground as the original Dockerfile intends.

I initially tested running apache2-foreground from within entrypoint.sh, and it also works, but I think that is a less "transparent" approach, and I guess for even better decoupling, in order to allow the authors of the original Dockerfile to change the CMD in their Dockerfile and my set-up not break as a result, I should pass whatever their CMD was into my Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT definition, sort of like...

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh", CMD]
```

But I don't know if that's possible is it?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you still have this problem, but maybe adding this will help you. I mean, it resolved my problem - PHP scripts running on the container didn't have write permissions.

```
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

For permissions problems with docker and WordPress to install plugins, templates or create folders you can use the command `COPY` with chown parameter in **Dockerfile**. Like below:

```
COPY [--chown=<user>:<group>] <src>... <dest>
```

For example, in my code runnig wordpress, I use:

```
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data ./app/ /var/www/html/
```

But you need had the last version of Docker to use chown parameter. A lot of people get the unknown chown parameter, this occurs because of Docker version. So before use chown I indicate to update your Docker.

> Docker reference about COPY command: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy
>
> Wordpress reference about permissions and www-data user: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Answer (score 0):

The php docker image itself, has it's own `command` entry and `entrypoint` as you can see [in its `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/ddc7084c8a78ea12f0cfdceff7d03c5a530b787e/5.6/apache/Dockerfile), and you're overriding them. So, instead of running `apache2-foreground` as it should, it runs your custom command and entrypoint, which creates the directories, change permissions and exits. Please note that there has to be a long running process for the container to stay up.

Instead you can add the following commands to the Dockerfile (haven't ran this, errors may occur):

```
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/ && chown www-data /var/www/html/maps && chgrp www-data /var/www/html/maps
```

or if you don't care about running them in a single layer, you can break them in separate `RUN` statements.

You should also remove the following lines:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 0755 /entrypoint.sh
```

then run `docker-compose build webserver` again

Comment: Thanks @Fortis, you are right about overriding the CMD in the original Dockerfile I'd not spotted that - but the problem with not using an entrypoint script as you suggest is that when I then mount the code from my local file system from /var/www/html in the container, the changes we've already made from Dockerfile inside /var/www/html get overwritten.  With your help I've found an answer using entrypoint script - please see my answer and let me know what you think maybe...

Answer (score 0):

The php:5.6-apache image has already an entrypoint defined.

If you override it with a custom script, you need to call the original entrypoint in order for the image to work.

Check [here](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/ddc7084c8a78ea12f0cfdceff7d03c5a530b787e/5.6/apache/Dockerfile), you'll see that the original entrypoint is

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-php-entrypoint"]
```

You can try executing it from your script, such as:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir /var/www/html/maps
chown www-data /var/www/html/maps
chgrp www-data /var/www/html/maps
docker-php-entrypoint "$@"
```

this is untested but should work.

Comment: Thanks @whites11 - you are right about me overriding the the CMD, I'd not understood that - but when I implemented your suggestion, whilst the endpoint.sh is run & the directories created etc., the webserver never webserver container still fails to come up - docker-compose logs gives:
 "gastrakweb_webserver_1 exited with code 0"  - but your answer helped me figured it out I think - please see/ comment on my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can add those commands (COPY, CHMOD) inside docker file it self.

```
# Copy FileDirectory public html pages
  COPY FileDirectory/var/www/html /var/www/html
  RUN chmod +x /var/www/html
```

Have a look at my docker file https://github.com/RohanMohite/Docker-Nginx-PHP/blob/master/server1/Dockerfile

If you need any further information to setup Dockerize PHP application then have a look at https://devopsdevelopment.wordpress.com/2017/08/02/how-to-configure-docker-with-nginx-and-php-application/

Please let me known.

Comment: Thanks, except I don't want to COPY nor chmod.  As per the question I want to mount a local volume from docker-compose (for instance in a dev environment where you want to have local edit-ability of those files), then create and chown/ chmod a directory inside it so the web server has the ability to write into it.